# iAd not showing on published app

Tags: ios, app-store, submit, iad

I have an app which has been submitted and accepted by the appstore on Saturday. I have added the right framework and everything and in the simulator it shows. In the iTunes Connect I already set the app to support iAds(before submitting it) and my contract was accepted yesterday evening, even though of that, woth my internet connection functional, I am not able to see the ads. Do i have to send another version for the contract to be valid? O does it just get a delay.

Answer (score 0):

iAds shows test ads in simulator. In live app it fetches from the server and depending on availability , the ads might or might not show up.

You can implement the delegate methods of [AdBannerViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) to listen for any error in loading , and log it to see which error occurs in loading.